# mapstruct - map object with nested list to flat list

Tags: mapstruct

I cannot manage a problem that seems to be trivial.

I just want to map relation to flat table.

```java
class Train {
  Integer trainNumber;
  List<Station> stations;
}

class Station {
  String name;
  String coords;
}
```

I want to map this classes to flatten one

```java
class TrainStation {
  Integer trainNumber;
  String stationName;
}
```

How to do this with mapstruct?